# How set credentialsencoding with apache android httpclient

Tags: android, apache-httpclient-4.x, resttemplate, spring-4, androidhttpclient

I have been using the build-in android httpclient and Springs Android Resttemplate (1.0.0.M4) in my Android app. I'm authenticating with Basic Auth.

I have a couple of things i need to set when making requests, most importantly credentials charset. Default is US-Ascii and nordic characters doesn't work unless i set it to ISO-8859.

I did that using the HttpClient:

```
    HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
    Credentials defaultcreds = new UsernamePasswordCredentials(msisdn, password);
    httpClient.getState().setCredentials(new AuthScope(AuthScope.ANY_HOST, AuthScope.ANY_PORT, AuthScope.ANY_REALM), defaultcreds);
    httpClient.getParams().setSoTimeout(prefs.getServerTimeout());
    httpClient.getParams().setConnectionManagerTimeout(3000);
    httpClient.getParams().setContentCharset("UTF-8");
    httpClient.getParams().setCredentialCharset("ISO-8859-1", )
```

I'm now trying to upgrade my libraries, and also get rid of the built-in httpclient dependency.

SO, i'm upgrading to resttemplate 2.0, and have imported apache's httpclient-android. I'm using Maven, so my dependencies are:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.android</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-android-rest-template</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.M3</version>
        <!--version>1.0.0.M4</version-->
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient-android</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.5.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

I have a hard time making this work as i want...

1. Neither of the jars above have a HttpClient class anywhere. Since the Android one is deprecated, i don't want to rely on that one.
2. According to the docs, Basic Auth should be performed as per the below code. But i cannot find anywhere to set the credentials charset!

   HttpAuthentication authHeader = new HttpBasicAuthentication(msisdn, password);
   HttpHeaders requestHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
   requestHeaders.setAuthorization(authHeader);
   HttpEntity requestEntity = new HttpEntity(requestHeaders);

It would be great if someone could help me out.

Comment: `cz.msebera.android:httpclient:4.4.1.1` has `cz.msebera.android.httpclient.client.HttpClient`. That's what I used in [this book sample](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Internet/HTTPStacks) and [this NetCipher code](https://github.com/guardianproject/NetCipher/tree/master/libnetcipher-httpclient). With regards to basic auth charsets, I have no idea.

Comment: Right, thanks. Unfortunately that doesn't work with Spring's RestClient, so i'd have to figure out another way to to the rest->object work and test it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the deprecated Apache HTTP client on Android you can add it to the build by `useLibrary` declaration of Android Gradle plugin:

```
android {
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}
```

You can find more info here: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#behavior-apache-http-client

Unfortunately I don't think there is a way how to add the HTTP client to the on your own.

**UPDATE:**
There is an issue filed to `RestTemplate` project to allow standalone Apache HTTP client: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-android/issues/31